# Neglected services on old DC - how to move to new DC?

Tags: domain-controller, windows-server-2012-r2, ntp, nis

We have installed a new Server 2012.

The new server: DC3 (192.168.0.3), has been promoted, and is now our main DC (includes : DNS, DHCP)

```
Schema master               DC3.domain
Domain naming master        DC3.domain
PDC                         DC3.domain
RID pool manager            DC3.domain
Infrastructure master       DC3.domain
The command completed successfully.
```

My next step is to kill the old DC (DC1 - 192.168.0.1)

But before doing that, I see some residue, that I don't understand how to handle.

Looking at my DC3 DHCP server options, I see the following, under the "scope options"

[image]

Q: Which of these values I have still not transferred to the new DC3 ?

What should be my next step?

Comment: Just demote it. The DHCP options will end up changing over (and if they don't, you can do it yourself).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those options are directing clients to the 192.168.0.1 server for these particular services. You should verify that the clients aren't actually using any of these services before you start migrating away.

If you're using only Windows clients then it's really doubtful that you're using NIS (a directory service protocol for Unix-based machines), so it's probably safe to remove the 041 DHCP option.

Likewise, if you're using only Windows clients then the 042 DHCP option is probably also doing nothing. Some non-Windows clients do honor this option, but no Windows version will use that option. (Domain-joined Windows clients will pull their time sync information from a Domain Controller automatically.)

Option 044 directs Windows clients to a WINS server for NetBIOS name resolution. If you are still using applications that require NetBIOS name resolution and you find that you were running a WINS server on your old Domain Controller (DC) then it might make sense to install the WINS Server role onto your new DC and update this DHCP option to reflect your new DC's IP address. (NetBIOS is becoming a lot less important, but there's always a chance that you still have something legacy that needs it.)

It's highly doubtful that you're really using a NetBIOS Datagram Distribution server, which is what option 045 refers to. Microsoft WINS doesn't even support this functionality anyway. OS/2 is the only operating system that I'm aware of that actually uses this functionality. I can't imagine you wouldn't be safe to remove this option.

Comment: Thanks. I do have some mac is clients, how will that effect ?

Comment: I don't think you're going to see any effect to Mac-based clients w/ those options.